# Hadoop : HDFS space quota

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Does there any way to check if there is any space quota applied on a specific HDFS directory ?

I cannot find any kind of command that give such information [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#dfsadmin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you missed this page?

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html#Administrative_Commands

> an extension to the count command of the HDFS shell reports quota values and the current count of names and bytes in use.
>
> `hadoop fs -count -q [-h] [-v] <directory>...<directory>`
>
> With the -q option, also report the name quota value set for each directory, the available name quota remaining, the space quota value set, and the available space quota remaining. If the directory does not have a quota set, the reported values are none and inf. The -h option shows sizes in human readable format. The -v option displays a header line